# How to replace data in a table with javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Screenshot of the result so far
[image]
 I have 2 problems with this code. Firstly, I want to click the button "calculate the average" and it will replace the question mark with the average value; but it only works for the first student. It doesn't work with the second or third student. I have tried to change id="question" to class, but it still doesn't work. Secondly, I want to click the "find students with good result button" and it will highlight the data in the whole row in red (the font color, not the background color) for students with average >=8. I have worked on this 3 days but still cannot get it to work. I'm much appreciated if anyone can help me to debug this.Thanks :-)

```js
var fullname = document.getElementById("name");
var classnumber = document.getElementById("classnumber");
var maths = document.getElementById("maths");
var physics = document.getElementById("physics");
var chemistry = document.getElementById("chemistry");
var notice1 = document.getElementById("notice1");
var notice2 = document.getElementById("notice2");
var notice3 = document.getElementById("notice3");
var notice4 = document.getElementById("notice4");
var notice5 = document.getElementById("notice5");
var student = [];


function submit() {
  var isValid = true;
  if (fullname.value === "") {
    notice1.innerHTML = "Full name must be entered";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice1.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (classnumber.value === "") {
    notice2.innerHTML = "Class must be entered";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice2.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(maths.value)) === true || maths.value === "" || parseFloat(maths.value) > 10 || parseFloat(maths.value) < 0) {
    notice3.innerHTML = "Maths score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice3.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(physics.value)) === true || physics.value === "" || parseFloat(physics.value) > 10 || parseFloat(physics.value) < 0) {
    notice4.innerHTML = "Physics score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice4.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(chemistry.value)) === true || chemistry.value === "" || parseFloat(chemistry.value) > 10 || parseFloat(chemistry.value) < 0) {
    notice5.innerHTML = "Chemistry score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice5.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isValid === true) {
    addStudent(fullname.value, maths.value, physics.value, chemistry.value);
    transfer();
  }
  return false;
}

function addStudent(fullname, maths, physics, chemistry) {
  var newStudent = {
    fullname: fullname,
    maths: maths,
    physics: physics,
    chemistry: chemistry,
  };
  student.push(newStudent);
}

function round(num, decimals) {
  var n = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return Math.round((n * num).toFixed(decimals)) / n;
}

function transfer() {
  var content = document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML;
  var i = student.length - 1;
  content += "<tr>";
  content += "<td>" + (i + 1) + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].fullname + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].maths + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].physics + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].chemistry + " </td>";
  content += "<td id='question'>" + "?" + "</td>";
  content += "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML = content;
  this.studentmaths = student[i].maths;
  this.studentphysics = student[i].physics;
  this.studentchemistry = student[i].chemistry;
}

function average() {
  var calculation = round((parseFloat(parseInt(studentmaths) + parseInt(studentphysics) + parseInt(studentchemistry)) / 3), 2);
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = calculation;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(goodresult).click(function() {
    if ($('question').val >= 8) {
      content.css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Full name</td>
      <td><input id="name"></td>
      <td id="notice1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Class</td>
      <td><input id="classnumber"></td>
      <td id="notice2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Maths Score</td>
      <td><input id="maths"></td>
      <td id="notice3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Physics Score</td>
      <td><input id="physics"></td>
      <td id="notice4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Chemistry Score</td>
      <td><input id="chemistry"></td>
      <td id="notice5"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;"></td>
      <td><button style="border:none; background-color:white;font-size: 15px;" onclick="submit();">Submit</button></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="tableData" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Number</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 70px">Full Name</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Maths</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Physics</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Chemistry</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Average</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button style="float:left;display:block;clear:both;border:none;background-color: white;padding:10px;position: absolute;left:600px" onclick="average();">Calculate the average</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button style="float:left; display:block;clear: both;border:none;background-color: white;padding:10px;position: absolute;left:600px" id="goodresult">Find students with good result</button>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just calculate the average when you hit submit and it puts the student in the table? That would be very simple and largely solve the problem. That 'Calculate Average' seems like an unnecessary button. I don't know your exact needs, but if I used this, I would just want all the data there initially, not hit another button to get average.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery.js"></script>
            <style>
                td {padding:5px;}
                input {border:solid 1px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
           <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;">Full name</td>
                <td><input id="name"></td>
                <td id="notice1"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;">Class</td>
                <td><input id="classnumber"></td>
                <td id="notice2"></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;">Maths Score</td>
                <td><input id="maths"></td>
                <td id="notice3"></td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;">Physics Score</td>
                <td><input id="physics"></td>
                <td id="notice4"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;">Chemistry Score</td>
                <td><input id="chemistry"></td>
                <td id="notice5"></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td style="width:150px;"></td>
                <td><button style="border:none; background-color:white;font-size: 15px;" onclick="submit();">Submit</button></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           <table id="tableData" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th style="padding:5px 30px">Number</th>
                <th style="padding:5px 70px">Full Name</th>
                <th style="padding:5px 30px">Maths</th>
                <th style="padding:5px 30px">Physics</th>
                <th style="padding:5px 30px">Chemistry</th>
                <th style="padding:5px 30px">Average</th>
            </tr>
           </table>
           <br>
           <button style="float:left; display:block;clear: both;border:none;background-color: white;padding:10px;position: absolute;left:600px" id="goodresult">Find students with good result</button>

           <script type="text/javascript">
            var fullname = document.getElementById("name");
            var classnumber = document.getElementById("classnumber");
            var maths = document.getElementById("maths");
            var physics = document.getElementById("physics");
            var chemistry = document.getElementById("chemistry");
            var notice1 = document.getElementById("notice1");
            var notice2 = document.getElementById("notice2");
            var notice3 = document.getElementById("notice3");
            var notice4 = document.getElementById("notice4");
            var notice5 = document.getElementById("notice5");
            var student=[];


            function submit () {
                var isValid = true;
                if (fullname.value === "") {
                    notice1.innerHTML = "Full name must be entered";
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    notice1.innerHTML = "";             
                }
                if (classnumber.value==="") {
                    notice2.innerHTML="Class must be entered";
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    notice2.innerHTML = "";             
                }
                if (isNaN(parseInt(maths.value))===true || maths.value==="" || parseFloat(maths.value)>10 || parseFloat(maths.value)<0) {
                    notice3.innerHTML="Maths score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    notice3.innerHTML="";               
                }
                if (isNaN(parseInt(physics.value))===true || physics.value==="" || parseFloat(physics.value)>10 || parseFloat(physics.value)<0) {
                    notice4.innerHTML="Physics score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    notice4.innerHTML="";               
                }
                if (isNaN(parseInt(chemistry.value))===true || chemistry.value==="" || parseFloat(chemistry.value)>10 || parseFloat(chemistry.value)<0) {
                    notice5.innerHTML="Chemistry score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
                    isValid = false;
                } else {
                    notice5.innerHTML="";               
                }
                if (isValid === true) {
                    addStudent(fullname.value, maths.value, physics.value, chemistry.value);
                    transfer();                 
                }
                return false;
            }
            function addStudent(fullname, maths, physics, chemistry) {
                var newStudent = {                  
                    fullname  : fullname,
                    maths : maths,
                    physics : physics,
                    chemistry : chemistry,
                };              
                student.push(newStudent);
            }
            function round(num, decimals) {
                var n = Math.pow(10, decimals);
                return Math.round( (n * num).toFixed(decimals) )  / n;
            }
            function transfer() {               
                var content = document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML;
                var i= student.length-1;
                var scoreAverage = (parseInt(student[i].maths) + parseInt(student[i].physics) + parseInt(student[i].chemistry)) / 3;
                console.log(scoreAverage);
                console.log(parseInt(student[i].maths));
                content += "<tr>";
                content += "<td>" + (i+1) +" </td>";
                content += "<td>" + student[i].fullname +" </td>";
                content += "<td>" + student[i].maths +" </td>";
                content += "<td>" + student[i].physics +" </td>";
                content += "<td>" + student[i].chemistry +" </td>";
                content += "<td class='average'>" +scoreAverage+"</td>";
                content += "</tr>";                         
                document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML=content;
                this.studentmaths=student[i].maths;
                this.studentphysics=student[i].physics;
                this.studentchemistry=student[i].chemistry;
            }
            function average() {
                var calculation=round((parseFloat(parseInt(studentmaths) + parseInt(studentphysics) + parseInt(studentchemistry))/3),2);
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=calculation;
            }
            $(document).ready(function (){
              $('#goodresult').click(function(){
               
                $('.average').each(function() {
                  if(parseInt($(this)[0].innerHTML) >= 8){
                    $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
                  }
                });
             });
            });
           </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is an example. Note: when accessing items with their id, use $('#id-of-thing'), I noticed multiple times you simply used $(id-of-thing) with no quotes or pound sign. Or $('id-of-thing') with no pound sign. When accessing an element by its class, use $('.class-of-thing') (note the '.' before the class name).

This calculates averages on submit, and then correctly highlights the cells red when you try to find good scores (I may suggest green for good scores? Green usually means good and red usually means bad).

To access each cell individually, you can make use of the $('.element').each(function(){ do stuff }); which I do in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the problems with my code now :-)

Answer (score 0):

While calculating the average you are using `id` and even calculating the `average of last entered record` in the function. So we will update that thing first changing id to class and calculating the average for each record and then inserting it to average column.

And for the second problem, we will go through all the averages and check if anything is more than 8 then we will add css to that like this :)

```js
var fullname = document.getElementById("name");
var classnumber = document.getElementById("classnumber");
var maths = document.getElementById("maths");
var physics = document.getElementById("physics");
var chemistry = document.getElementById("chemistry");
var notice1 = document.getElementById("notice1");
var notice2 = document.getElementById("notice2");
var notice3 = document.getElementById("notice3");
var notice4 = document.getElementById("notice4");
var notice5 = document.getElementById("notice5");
var student = [];


function submit() {
  var isValid = true;
  if (fullname.value === "") {
    notice1.innerHTML = "Full name must be entered";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice1.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (classnumber.value === "") {
    notice2.innerHTML = "Class must be entered";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice2.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(maths.value)) === true || maths.value === "" || parseFloat(maths.value) > 10 || parseFloat(maths.value) < 0) {
    notice3.innerHTML = "Maths score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice3.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(physics.value)) === true || physics.value === "" || parseFloat(physics.value) > 10 || parseFloat(physics.value) < 0) {
    notice4.innerHTML = "Physics score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice4.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isNaN(parseInt(chemistry.value)) === true || chemistry.value === "" || parseFloat(chemistry.value) > 10 || parseFloat(chemistry.value) < 0) {
    notice5.innerHTML = "Chemistry score must be entered and it has to be a number from 0 to 10";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    notice5.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (isValid === true) {
    addStudent(fullname.value, maths.value, physics.value, chemistry.value);
    transfer();
  }
  return false;
}

function addStudent(fullname, maths, physics, chemistry) {
  var newStudent = {
    fullname: fullname,
    maths: maths,
    physics: physics,
    chemistry: chemistry,
  };
  student.push(newStudent);
}

function round(num, decimals) {
  var n = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return Math.round((n * num).toFixed(decimals)) / n;
}

function transfer() {
  var content = document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML;
  var i = student.length - 1;
  content += "<tr>";
  content += "<td>" + (i + 1) + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].fullname + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].maths + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].physics + " </td>";
  content += "<td>" + student[i].chemistry + " </td>";
  content += "<td class='question'>" + "?" + "</td>";
  content += "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("tableData").innerHTML = content;
  this.studentmaths = student[i].maths;
  this.studentphysics = student[i].physics;
  this.studentchemistry = student[i].chemistry;
}

function average() {
  var rows = document.getElementById("tableData").rows.length
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var calculation = round((parseFloat(parseInt(student[i].maths) + parseInt(student[i].physics) + parseInt(student[i].chemistry)) / 3), 2);
    document.getElementsByClassName("question")[i].innerHTML = calculation;
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(goodresult).click(function() {
    var ques = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
    for (var i = 0; i < ques.length; i++) {
      if ($(ques[i]).text() >= 8) {
        $(ques[i]).parent("tr").css("color","red");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Full name</td>
      <td><input id="name"></td>
      <td id="notice1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Class</td>
      <td><input id="classnumber"></td>
      <td id="notice2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Maths Score</td>
      <td><input id="maths"></td>
      <td id="notice3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Physics Score</td>
      <td><input id="physics"></td>
      <td id="notice4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;">Chemistry Score</td>
      <td><input id="chemistry"></td>
      <td id="notice5"></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;"></td>
      <td><button style="border:none; background-color:white;font-size: 15px;" onclick="submit();">Submit</button></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="tableData" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Number</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 70px">Full Name</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Maths</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Physics</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Chemistry</th>
      <th style="padding:5px 30px">Average</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button style="float:left;display:block;clear:both;border:none;background-color: white;padding:10px;position: absolute;left:600px" onclick="average();">Calculate the average</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button style="float:left; display:block;clear: both;border:none;background-color: white;padding:10px;position: absolute;left:600px" id="goodresult">Find students with good result</button>
```

P.S. Changes are done in javascript part in `function average()` and `$(goodresult).click(function() {})`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer gives me some ideas to change my code :-)

Comment: @Anthony If it helped please accept and upvote the answer :)